# ORDER BY query giving two different outputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a student table with 8 records in columns [name, address, TotalFees].

Even though I execute two same `ORDER BY` queries on single table I get two different outputs. I have attached the screenshot below.

Same query on same table with different output:

[image]

Comment: Both of them are producing results consistent with the guarantees that *you* have requested in your `ORDER BY`. If you want stronger guarantees, *you* have to request them by adding additional column(s) or expression(s) to that `ORDER BY`.

Comment: This is a very good example, that there is **absolutely no implicit sort order** Each call might come back with a different order, as long as your columns for `ORDER BY` are not `UNIQUE` in their combined values.

Comment: ... and what is your question?

Comment: **But my only concern is that why the #3rd result in the second output table changes when i want to reflect only top 3 values from the first output table.**

Comment: Because there are 720 possible different orderings for the result returned by your first query and all of them are consistent with what you asked for. Just about anything *could* change which, *specific* ordering is returned by that query. In some circumstances, just running that same query twice in a row *could* have returned results in different orders. Your second query is consistent with 120 of those possible orderings. The server is free to process result sets in whichever order is most convenient for it, provided it fits within the bounds of what you've said is required - `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that you have is that the keys for the `order by` do not uniquely define each row.  In particular, "khar" is repeated for most of the rows (your results suggest that you are using a case-insensitive collation).

In SQL databases, the sort is not stable.  A stable sort is one that preserves the original ordering of values with the same key.  Because the sort is not stable, the results -- for identical keys -- can come out in any order.

Why isn't the sort stable?  That is easy in retrospect.  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no initial ordering, so the sorting is not stable.

The normal way to address this is to include a unique id as the final key in the `order by`:  `order by address, id`.  With your data, though, it is unclear what the unique key is.

Comment: **But my only concern is that why the #3rd result in the second output table changes when i want to reflect only top 3 values from the first output table.**

Comment: @NiKhilKutewalla . . . Because the `order by` has duplicate values for the keys, so it can produce different results each time it is run.  I think this explains what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of Address and Name won't produce duplicates so you can try this,

```
select *From student
order by address,name

select top 3 * From student
order by address,name
```

Comment: **But my only concern is that why the #3rd result in the second output table changes when i want to reflect only top 3 values from the first output table.**